# MSAL for OpenIdConnect?

Tags: asp.net, owin, openid-connect, azure-ad-msal, adal

we have 3 web apps which use OpenIdConnect with the OWIN app builder for user sign in. The packages used in the Startup are:

```
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect;
```

This is the Configuration method, some code skipped for brevity:

```
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = clientId,
                Authority = commonAuthority,
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
                RedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
                TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    RoleClaimType = "roles",
                },

                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                {
                    AuthorizationCodeReceived = AuthorizationCodeReceived,
                    AuthenticationFailed = context =>
                    {
                        context.HandleResponse();
                        context.Response.Redirect("/Error/ShowError?signIn=true&errorMessage=" + context.Exception.Message);
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }
                }
            });
    }
```

I don't see any mention of `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory` (ADAL) anywhere in the Startup code. Correct me if I am wrong but I think there is no action to be taken as part of ADAL to MSAL for OpenIdConnect authentication components.